# How to resolve this error Type 'FirebaseUser' is not a subtype of type 'String'?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I am getting this exception while running my app:

> type 'FirebaseUser' is not a subtype of type 'String'

The app is working. It does the phone authentication and then move to the next page based on same given condition. But when i hit the back button it throws the exception also in the app it is visible.

This is my code.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'AccountDetialsPage.dart';
import 'Homepage.dart';
import 'Phoneverification.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final Firestore firestore = Firestore.instance;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: FutureBuilder(
          future: getCurrentUser(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
              return Text("Loading...");
            }

            return StreamBuilder(
            stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
            builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData){
                return StreamBuilder(
                  stream: firestore
                      .collection('users')
                      .document(snapshot.data)
                      .snapshots(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot){
                      if (snapshot.hasData){
                        if (snapshot.data["verified"] == true){
                          return HomePage();
                        }
                        else{
                          return AccountDetialsPage();
                        }
                      }
                    else{
                      return Text('Loading StreamBuilder');
                      }                  
                    }

                );

              }
              else{
                return Phoneverification();
              }
            },
            );
          }),
    );
  }

  Future<String> getCurrentUser() async {
    final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    final FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();
    final uid = user.uid;
    var number = user.phoneNumber;
    return number.toString();

  }
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzwT7.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your `StreamBuilder` you set the future to:

```
stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
```

And then use that in the builder to get data from Firestore with:

```
  stream: firestore
      .collection('users')
      .document(snapshot.data)
      .snapshots(),
```

The `onAuthStateChanged` listener is invoked with a `FirebaseUser`, so `snapshot.data` in here is a `FirebaseUser`. Since `document(...)` expects a string, that's what you get an error about.

Most likely you're looking to use the UID of the user to look up the document, in which case you'd do:

```
  stream: firestore
      .collection('users')
      .document(snapshot.data.uid)
      .snapshots(),
```

---

In general your code looks confusing though: in the `FutureBuilder` you have a future for the current user, and then in your stream builder you also use a listener for that same user.

My feeling is that you're actually trying to use a `FutureBuilder` for the user, and then a `StreamBuilder` for the data from Firestore. If that is the case, you're probably looking for something more like:

```
home: FutureBuilder(
  future: getCurrentUser(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.connectionState != ConnectionState.done) {
      return Text("Loading...");
    }

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: firestore
              .collection('users')
              .document(snapshot.data)
              .snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData){
            if (snapshot.data["verified"] == true){
              return HomePage();
            }
            else{
              return AccountDetialsPage();
            }
          }
      }
    },
    );
  }),
```

There might be typos in the above, but the important thing is that the first `stream` here contains the snapshots from Firestore based on the `future: getCurrentUser()`.

Comment: Hi Frank thanks for your quick response ... But my requirement is to check first whether any user is logged in or not if logged in perform the one you wrote else it will do the phone Authentication stuff... Could you please help me out.

Comment: The first part of my answer does that, and simply fixes the error you get.

Comment: Yups but it will remove my authentication... I cant use that code... Cant i  have both the things together

Comment: The first section doesn't remove any authentication. It merely fixes the mistake you made. Please try it again. If you can't get it to work, edit your question to show the updated code where you applied the change in the first part of my answer.

Comment: Sir i am getting really confused ... If you look at my question there is page called PhoneVerification page which does the phone auth stuff.. Please let me know where will i place that

Comment: I am not sure how to make the first part of my answer clearer. To get rid of the `type 'FirebaseUser' is not a subtype of type 'String'` error message, you need to replace `.document(snapshot.data)` with `.document(snapshot.data.uid)`. If you can't get it to work, edit your question to show the updated code and the problem it now gives.